# How to configure a RestItemWriter to progress a patch request in Spring Boot Starter Batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, http, post

I have a requirement to create a batch process that runs through 80,000+ records and stores it in a new DB via a patch request.

I can create an ItemReader with FlatFileReader and I created a CustomeProcessor by implementing the ItemProcessor but not sure how to do a RestItemWriter with patch request.

I found a difficulty in that I'm unable to make a patch call with RestTemplate.

Could someone please help me with the RestItemWriter implementation?

I tried creating the RestItemWriter but not sure how to make the patch request from it.

Comment: According to documentation you can only use POST or PUT. https://docs.jboss.org/jberet/latest/javadoc/jberet-support/org/jberet/support/io/RestItemReaderWriterBase.html#httpMethod

Comment: is there any other way to make the patch call by adding any dependencies in my project?